# Count of Value column with case when and group by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Table:

```
Date            Id       Value                    
2019-02-09      a1       ab            
2019-01-12      a2       cd
2019-12-12      a1       ab
2017-07-23      a1       ab
2018-12-09      a1       ab
2018-12-28      a1       cd
2016-11-09      a2       cd
2016-05-19      a2       ab
```

Output:

```
      Id        Max-Min               
      a1        1     
      a2       -1
```

The aim is to create `Max_year_count-Min_year_count per Id`.
For example, calculation in `Value column` :
 `(count of occurrence of value in max_year with group by Id)-(count of occurrence of value in min_year with group by Id)`
Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oracle supports [FIRST/LAST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) for aggregates:

```
SELECT id,
    -- latest year's count
    Count(*) KEEP (Dense_Rank LAST  ORDER BY Extract(YEAR From "Date"))
     -- oldest year's count
  - Count(*) KEEP (Dense_Rank FIRST ORDER BY Extract(YEAR From "Date"))
FROM DATA
GROUP BY Id
```

Comment: For some reason first/last never sticks in my brain... this should definitely be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a derived table of the maximum and minimum years for each `Id` value, and then count the number of years for that `id` value which match those values and subtract them to get `Max-Min`:

```
SELECT d.Id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Date") = Max_Year THEN 1 END) -
       COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Date") = Min_Year THEN 1 END) AS "Max-Min"
FROM data d
JOIN (SELECT Id, 
             MAX(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Date")) AS Max_Year,
             MIN(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "Date")) AS Min_Year
      FROM data
      GROUP BY Id) m ON m.Id = d.Id
GROUP BY d.Id
```

Output:

```
ID  Max-Min
a1  1
a2  -1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25f4cb633dc786cdc96880db09c769af)